# oracle forms: max clause inside a where clause in pl/sql

Tags: forms, oracle, plsql, max, oracleforms

> select balance from newrecord where s_no in(select max(s_no) from
>   newrecord) into :summary.Bal ;

**how do you transform this from sql to pl/sql?**

explanation: selecting a balance from the table newrecord where s_no (serial number) a member of newrecord is max so lets say if it starts from 1 to 6 will choose to show the balance with s_no = 6 , :summary.Bal  is a text item to show the balance

Comment: yes error 103 , "encountered the symbol 'into' when expecting one of the following ; for and or group having intersect with minus order start union where connect the symbol ; was inserted before into to continue"

Comment: tried to use the code as is, since searching for an equivalent in pl/sql came out with no luck in google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper syntax:

```
select <field_name> into <variable_name> from <rest of query>
```

Also, no need for the IN operator in your query, just write =

```
... where s_no = (select max(s_no) from newrecord)
```

Comment: perfect i knew it had to be something there , thank you.

Comment: If this solved the issue, please mark your question as answered so it doesn't show up on the list of unanswered questions. Cheers!